# SQL Count Rows GROUP BY Month Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have a table and it has the following structure:

```
   DEVICE_ID |    DATE    |  STATUS
------------------------------------------
       1     | 2021/01/05 | accepted
       2     | 2021/01/23 | success
       3     | 2021/02/07 | success
       4     | 2021/03/11 | accepted
       5     | 2021/03/20 | unsuccess
       6     | 2021/03/26 | success
```

I want to calculate no of records in 2021 by **status** and `GROUP BY` month name like this :

```
     MONTH    | ACCEPTED | SUCCESS | UNSUCCESS 
------------------------------------------------
    January   |    1     |    1    |     0
    February  |    0     |    1    |     0
    March     |    1     |    1    |     1
    April     |    0     |    0    |     0
    May       |    0     |    0    |     0
    June      |    0     |    0    |     0
    July      |    0     |    0    |     0
    August    |    0     |    0    |     0
    September |    0     |    0    |     0
    October   |    0     |    0    |     0
    November  |    0     |    0    |     0
    December  |    0     |    0    |     0
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: I suspect the down-vote is because you haven't shown what you've tried so far. Here are some hints to get you started: you can use ROW_NUMBER to get the DEVICE_ID, DATENAME(month, [DATE]) to get the month name, and PIVOT to get it into columns.

Comment: @RussellFox I don't agree (although it wasn't me either). The reason for downvoting is clear from the popup on the arrow. And it this case it's totally justified. No visible effort and the question is unclear because there is no question. It's not clear what keeps OP from doing what they want. Also, some people feel heavily offended when downvoted (not here luckily) and take it out on the one who dares to explain. *That's* unprofessional.

Comment: @DaleK Thank you dear friend, this below answers is working but my problem is in date format, my date format is in persian calendar and year is 1400 so sql server showing message that is out-of-range

Comment: @HadiRajabi ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation - because you want the full month list you need to be able to have all 12 months somewhere in the data. Then you want the custom status columns pivoted to display as you asked.

You should next time at least or tell us what you tried. It helps us figure out how youre thinking about it and how we can help you get past whatever roadblocks youve encountered.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp;
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDb..#tmp2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp2;

CREATE TABLE #tmp
    (
        Device_ID INT
        , Date VARCHAR(12)
        , Status VARCHAR(15)
    )
;

CREATE TABLE #tmp2
    (
        MOnthName VARCHAR(25)
    )
;

INSERT INTO #tmp2 
    (MonthName) 
VALUES
    ('January'),
    ('February'),
    ('March'),
    ('April'),
    ('May'),
    ('June'),
    ('July'),
    ('August'),
    ('September'),
    ('October'),
    ('November'),
    ('December')
;

INSERT INTO #tmp
    (
        Device_ID
        , Date
        , Status
    )
VALUES
    (1,'2021/01/05','accepted'),
    (2,'2021/01/23','success'),
    (3,'2021/02/07','success'),
    (4,'2021/03/11','accepted'),
    (5,'2021/03/20','unsuccess'),
    (6,'2021/03/26','success')
;

SELECT 
    MOnthName
    , success
    , accepted
    , unsuccess
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            tt.MonthName
            , Status
        FROM 
            #tmp2 tt
            LEFT JOIN #tmp t ON tt.MOnthName = DATENAME(month, CAST(Date AS DATE))
        GROUP BY
            tt.MonthName 
            , Status
    ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
    (
        COUNT(Status) FOR Status IN ([accepted], [success], [unsuccess])
    ) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN MonthName ='January' THEN 1
        WHEN MonthName ='February' THEN 2
        WHEN MonthName ='March' THEN 3
        WHEN MonthName ='April' THEN 4
        WHEN MonthName ='May' THEN 5
        WHEN MonthName ='June' THEN 6
        WHEN MonthName ='July' THEN 7
        WHEN MonthName ='August' THEN 8
        WHEN MonthName ='September' THEN 9
        WHEN MonthName ='October' THEN 10
        WHEN MonthName ='November' THEN 11
        WHEN MonthName ='December' THEN 12
END
```

Comment: Thank You Dear For Quick Answer, my Date Field type is Varchar , Please Help to Convert to date

Comment: @HadiRajabi just change it to varchar and cast the varchar to date when youre getting DATENAME(CAST(date as date))

Comment: Cast is ok, now i need to limit to current year and how can i change months names in my culture?

Comment: @HadiRajabi Limiting to the current year should be eays in the where clause in the main query. You can literally say WHERE Date>='1/1/2021' or WHERE Date>'1/1/'+YEAR(GETDATE())

Comment: As far as changing month names, you'd need to be more specific about what youre after before i can help

Answer (score 1):

```
 create table yourtable(DEVICE_ID int, DATE date, STATUS varchar(50));
 
 insert into yourtable values(1, '2021/01/05' , 'accepted');
 insert into yourtable values(2, '2021/01/23' , 'success');
 insert into yourtable values(3, '2021/02/07' , 'success');
 insert into yourtable values(4, '2021/03/11' , 'accepted');
 insert into yourtable values(5, '2021/03/20' , 'unsuccess');
 insert into yourtable values(6, '2021/03/26' , 'success');
```

Query:

```
 ;WITH months(MonthNumber) AS
 (
     SELECT 0
     UNION ALL
     SELECT MonthNumber+1 
     FROM months
     WHERE MonthNumber < 11
 )
 SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,MonthNumber,'01-01-2021')) AS [month],
 coalesce(sum(case when status='ACCEPTED' then 1 end),0) ACCEPTED,
 coalesce(sum(case when status='SUCCESS' then 1 end),0) SUCCESS,
 coalesce(sum(case when status='UNSUCCESS' then 1 end),0) UNSUCCESS
 
 FROM months m left join yourtable y
 on m.monthnumber=month(y.[date])-1
 group by monthnumber
```

Output:

| month | ACCEPTED | SUCCESS | UNSUCCESS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| February | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| March | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| April | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| May | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| June | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| July | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| August | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| September | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| October | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| November | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| December | 0 | 0 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e05d7316d863c1b130d6f86fc2e4445)*

Comment: Thank you So Much For Quick Answer, the type of my date field is 'string' how can i convert to date without change structure?

Comment: how can i change month names in my calture?

Comment: What will be your desired month names?

Comment: my calendar is Shamsi (Jalali) and months names is like this:
1 = 'Farvardin'
2 = 'Ordibehesht'
3 = 'Khordad'
4 = 'Tir'
....